# Full screen photo picker for iPad in obj-c and xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have implemented the usual examples of accessing the camera roll on ipad and selecting a photo (I think). I'm a bit disappointed in the little tiny popout window that shows all my photos.  Im much more impressed by the way you can select a wallpaper on iPad, and the photo viewer.

So what I would really like to have is control that displays a full screen of camera roll thumbnails, which if you then select one, it displays full screen with options to move and scale, and then you can select that image.

Does anything like this already exist that I can use?  Do I have to roll my own?  Or is there something already built in that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody else has chimed in- and I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-ios-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I absolutely love [AGImagePickerController](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController).  It's big, it's cross platform, but most importantly, it allows multiple selection.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I will definitely check it out.  Do you know if it works full screen for iPad?  Or do I need to make some tweaks for that?

Comment: Yep.  It'a full screen cross platform